# MotionLayout collapses RecyclerView header but does not expand

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/siralam/MotionLayoutPlayground) that can reproduce this issue.

#### Expected Result

- When I scroll the bottom RecyclerView upwards, the top RecyclerView collapses
- When I scroll the bottom RecyclerView downwards, the top RecyclerView expands

#### Observed Result

- When I scroll the bottom RecyclerView downwards, the top RecyclerView does not expands

#### Additional information

- Try to hold your swipe when the top RecyclerView collapses at the half, and then swipe down. You can see half of the top items being cut.
- This only happens for the collapsing View being/includes a RecyclerView.

#### GIF

(Ignore the changing color - it is just a result of compressing GIF)

[image]

#### Question

Did I do anything wrong or it is a MotionLayout bug?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an alternative solution.

For easier communication, I will use `rvTop` for the top RecyclerView and `rvBottom` for the bottom RecyclerView.

Instead of "shrinking" rvTop, the idea is to "hide" it instead.

So instead of let rvBottom constraint to the bottom of rvTop, we need to introduce a new invisible line in between them, and use MotionLayout to animate this invisible line upwards, while keeping the alpha change of rvTop.

In order to do this, we have to make rvBottom opaque, otherwise it will overlap with the fading rvTop.

I have updated the code in the [sample project](https://github.com/siralam/MotionLayoutPlayground) to demonstrate the changes.

And the effect is:

[image]

#### EDIT:

Another alternative is to remove rvTop's constraint to top of parent after the transition.

Yes, this will make it simply scroll with the rvBottom; but we can add a little bit of `translationY` to make it "scroll slower than rvBottom".

This can handle the case where you cannot make rvBottom opaque, for example the page itself uses a gradient background.

The effect looks like this:

[image]